# Boolean value describing if the cell value is equal to “2585”

Tags: r, boolean

I have a data frame, df. For each element that comprises column 4 of " df ", how would I be able to write the Boolean value describing if the cell value is equal to “ 2585 ”. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I believe it to be along the lines of making 'if' statements.

e.g if 2585 then X=true

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,3),
                  y = c(5,4,6,7,8,3,2,4))
df$ind <- df[,"x"] == 3
df

  x y   ind
1 1 5 FALSE
2 1 4 FALSE
3 2 6 FALSE
4 3 7  TRUE
5 4 8 FALSE
6 5 3 FALSE
7 6 2 FALSE
8 3 4  TRUE
```

Replace 'x' with your 4th column and 3 with 2585